# awk: Merge rows with unique content to each row of same id

Tags: arrays, string, bash, awk, gsub

I have a list of entries, each separated by a line break where each entry is a comma-separated set of values. The comma separation is there to resemble values per column. Some entries map to the same id (first value in each entry) but have different countries and regions. (list below)

I am trying to group entries that share a common id, but which may otherwise have different countries and regions, to a single row entry where associated multiple countries and/or regions are appended to the corresponding column and separated from each other by a '%%% ' sequence.

So far, I have managed to somewhat achieve this via awk, but the side effect of my approach is that I now have duplicates for the regions column.

As such, I am unsure whether I should continue with my current awk-based approach or branch out to a more scalable solution that will handle the job.

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '{x=$1;$1="";ctry[x]=ctry[x]$10"%%% ";$10="";a[x]=$0; str=a[x]; }END{for(x in a){outputString=("\n" x a[x] ctry[x]"\n"); gsub (/%%% \n/,"",outputString); print outputString}}' list.csv > final.csv
```

Contents of list.csv:

```
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,Germany,809900,Chem CMI,066900,Europe
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,Poland,810000,Chem CMI,066900,APAC
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,Spain,810100,Chem CMI,066900,APAC
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,France,2810200,Chem CMI,066900,North America
456456,Ammonium Citrus Esther,f,SupraTex Chem Analysis, 475000, Nigeria,814600,Chem Sensory,129475,MEA (Middle East and Africa)
789789,Archive 9 BASES II,f,HydroCare,066900,Belgium,211500,Chem CMI,066900,CIS (Commonwealth of Independent States)
```

Current output:

```
789789,Archive 9 BASES II,f,HydroCare,066900,Belgium,211500,Chem CMI,066900,CIS (Commonwealth of Independent States)

456456,Ammonium Citrus Esther,f,SupraTex Chem Analysis, 475000, Nigeria,814600,Chem Sensory,129475,MEA (Middle East and Africa)

123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,France,2810200,Chem CMI,066900,Europe%%% APAC%%% APAC%%% North America
```

Expected output:

```
789789,Archive 9 BASES II,f,HydroCare,066900,Belgium,211500,Chem CMI,066900,CIS (Commonwealth of Independent States)

456456,Ammonium Citrus Esther,f,SupraTex Chem Analysis, 475000, Nigeria,814600,Chem Sensory,129475,MEA (Middle East and Africa)

123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,Germany%%% Poland%%% Spain%%% France,2810200,Chem CMI,066900,Europe%%% APAC%%% North America
```

Comment: why only France was considered for id 123123?

Comment: @stack0114106, corrected the output. It should of course contain all corresponding countries and not just France.

Comment: Your script doesn't produce the uodated `Current output`. In addition
I wonder why `Latin America`, `MEA (Middle East and Africa)`,
`CIS (Commonwealth of Independent States)` ... etc. are missing
in the updated `Expected output`. They did exist in the orignal post.
Would you please clarify how you want to handle the 6th field (country names)
and the 10th field (region names)?

Comment: @tshiono, I tried to provide a minimal example of the problem, so I removed some of the entries to make the issue more clear. country names and region names should be grouped into their respective columns, unique and separated by '%%% '.

Comment: Sorry, I have overlooked you have updated the `list.csv` as well. Now I've understood what you want and posted an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
awk -F, '{
    x=$1;
    if (!shown[x,$10]++)
        ctry[x]=ctry[x]$10"%%% ";
    if (!shown[x,$6]++)
        nation[x]=nation[x]$6"%%% ";
    a[x]=$1","$2","$3","$4","$5
    b[x]=$7","$8","$9
}
END{
    for(x in a){
        gsub (/%%% $/,"",nation[x]);
        gsub (/%%% $/,"",ctry[x]);
        print a[x]","nation[x]","b[x]","ctry[x]"\n";
    }
}' list.csv > final.csv
```

You'll see the script above is based on the OP's one with some refactoring and modifications. The point is the line: `if (!shown[x,$10]++)` and the following similar one which avoids the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
awk -F, '($1 in a){x=a[$1];len=split(x,arr,",");arr[6]=arr[6]"%%% "$6;y=arr[1];arr[10]=arr[10]"%%% "$10;for(i=2;i<=len;i++){y=y","arr[i];a[$1]=y;}next;}{a[$1]=$0;}END{for(i in a){print a[i];}}' file
```

Comment: This does solve the problem for both the country and region columns. However, it still results in duplicate (country and) region values, e.g. for APAC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl solution

```
$ cat ginzburg.txt
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,Germany,809900,Chem CMI,066900,Europe
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,Poland,810000,Chem CMI,066900,APAC
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,Spain,810100,Chem CMI,066900,APAC
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900,France,2810200,Chem CMI,066900,North America
456456,Ammonium Citrus Esther,f,SupraTex Chem Analysis, 475000, Nigeria,814600,Chem Sensory,129475,MEA (Middle East and Africa)
789789,Archive 9 BASES II,f,HydroCare,066900,Belgium,211500,Chem CMI,066900,CIS (Commonwealth of Independent States)

$ perl -F, -lanE ' $x=join(",",@F[0..4]);$kv{$x}=join(",",@F[6..8]);@t=@{$kv2{$x}};push(@t,$F[5]);$kv2{$x}=[@t]; @p=@{$kv3{$x}};push(@p,$F[-1]);$kv3{$x}=[@p]; END { for(keys %kv) { %tv=(); %tv=map{$_=>1} @{$kv3{$_}};print "$_ ",join("%%",@{$kv2{$_}})," ",$kv{$_},",",join("%%",keys %tv) } } ' ginzburg.txt
456456,Ammonium Citrus Esther,f,SupraTex Chem Analysis, 475000  Nigeria 814600,Chem Sensory,129475,MEA (Middle East and Africa)
123123, Shelf Life Test,f,Other,066900 Germany%%Poland%%Spain%%France 2810200,Chem CMI,066900,Europe%%North America%%APAC
789789,Archive 9 BASES II,f,HydroCare,066900 Belgium 211500,Chem CMI,066900,CIS (Commonwealth of Independent States)

$
```